# ¿como puedo reemplazar valores con dos filas con array en python?

Tags: python, array

necesito que el programa haga lo siguiente tiene que reemplazar el dato ingresado entre estas 2 "filas" que son asientos de un avión se tiene que reemplazar por una X, los for me tiran un error y agradecería otra forma de hacerlo, si no se puede hacer con las 2 filas en separado que se haga 1 fila pero con que cumpla el requisito de reemplazar por una x está bien

el error es el siguiente

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\Users\Fabian\Desktop\asssssss.py", line 23, in <module>
    z = np.searchsorted(fila1, x)
  File "<__array_function__ internals>", line 5, in searchsorted
  File "C:\Users\Fabian\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python39\site-packages\numpy\core\fromnumeric.py", line 1348, in searchsorted    return _wrapfunc(a, 'searchsorted', v, side=side, sorter=sorter)
  File "C:\Users\Fabian\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python39\site-packages\numpy\core\fromnumeric.py", line 58, in _wrapfunc     
    return bound(*args, **kwds)
ValueError: object too deep for desired array
```

```
import numpy as np
fila1 = np.array((
    [1, 2, 3],
    [7, 8, 9],
    [13, 14, 15],
    [19, 20, 21],
    [25, 26, 27],
    [31, 32, 33], 
    [37, 38, 39] 
    ))
fila2 = np.array((
    [4, 5, 6],
    [10, 11 ,12],
    [16, 17, 18],
    [22, 23 ,24],
    [28, 29, 30],
    [34, 35 ,36],
    [40, 41, 42]
    ))
for i in range(7):
    for k in range(3):
        x= int(input('eliga el numero de su asiento'))
        z = np.searchsorted(fila1, x)
```

Comment: ahí lo agregué al texto

Comment: si sabes que al utilizar un numpy array, no puedes cambiar el tipo de dato?

Answer (score 0):

No conozco numpy, así que encontre una solución que no requiere buscar nada: dado el número de asiento, obtiene directamente el arreglo y posición a ocupar.

```
while True:
    x= int(input('eliga el numero de su asiento'))
    x -= 1 # Trabajamos internamente con indices base 0
    fila = x // 3
    col = x % 3
    # Las filas impares van en fila1; las pares en fila2
    indice_fila = fila // 2
    if fila % 2:
        fila2[indice_fila][col] = '0'
        print(fila2)
    else:
        fila1[indice_fila][col] = '0'
        print(fila1)
```

Luego de ingresar el número de asiento, le restamos uno para trabajar sobre indices base-cero de ahi en adelante.

Pensemos primero en el caso simple: una sola fila de asientos. En este caso, la fila correspondiente sería `x // 3`.

Como hay dos filas/arreglos, vemos que en `fila1` quedarían las filas impares de esa fila única inicial, y en `fila2`, las filas pares. En resumen, tengo que mirar el número de fila obtenido. Si es par, lo busco en `fila2`; en caso contrario, en `fila1`. En ambos casos debo reducir el indice a la mitad.

Cómo el arreglo es de enteros, no puedo colocar una "X", así que por el momento usare el valor "0" como marca.

**Demo**

```
import numpy as np
fila1 = np.array((
    [1, 2, 3],
    [7, 8, 9],
    [13, 14, 15],
    [19, 20, 21],
    [25, 26, 27],
    [31, 32, 33],
    [37, 38, 39]
    ))
fila2 = np.array((
    [4, 5, 6],
    [10, 11 ,12],
    [16, 17, 18],
    [22, 23 ,24],
    [28, 29, 30],
    [34, 35 ,36],
    [40, 41, 42]
    ))

while True:
    x= int(input('eliga el numero de su asiento'))
    x -= 1 # Trabajamos internamente con indices base 0
    fila = x // 3
    col = x % 3
    # Las filas impares van en fila1; las pares en fila2
    indice_fila = fila // 2
    if fila % 2:
        fila2[indice_fila][col] = '0'
        print(fila2)
    else:
        fila1[indice_fila][col] = '0'
        print(fila1)
```

produce

```
eliga el numero de su asiento1
[[ 0  2  3]
 [ 7  8  9]
 [13 14 15]
 [19 20 21]
 [25 26 27]
 [31 32 33]
 [37 38 39]]
eliga el numero de su asiento2
[[ 0  0  3]
 [ 7  8  9]
 [13 14 15]
 [19 20 21]
 [25 26 27]
 [31 32 33]
 [37 38 39]]
eliga el numero de su asiento3
[[ 0  0  0]
 [ 7  8  9]
 [13 14 15]
 [19 20 21]
 [25 26 27]
 [31 32 33]
 [37 38 39]]
eliga el numero de su asiento4
[[ 0  5  6]
 [10 11 12]
 [16 17 18]
 [22 23 24]
 [28 29 30]
 [34 35 36]
 [40 41 42]]
eliga el numero de su asiento5
[[ 0  0  6]
 [10 11 12]
 [16 17 18]
 [22 23 24]
 [28 29 30]
 [34 35 36]
 [40 41 42]]
```

Answer (score 0):

A ver, no puedes cambiar el tipo de dato de un *numpy array* por lo que si quieres decir que `fila[0][0] = "X"` te dará un bonito error :). También puedes olvidarte de los `for`, puedes acceder a un dato en especifico con la notación anterior y puedes verificar si ese dato existe con un simple `if/else`.

```
fila = int(input("ingrese la fila: "))-1 #pedimos que ingrese la fila y le restamos 1
#verificamos si esa fila existe
if fila in range(len(fila1)):
   #pedimos la posicion del asiento y restamos 1
    asiento = int(input("ingrese la posicion del asiento: "))-1
    if asiento in range(len(fila1[fila])):
        fila1[fila][asiento] = 0
        print("Listo!")
```

De esta forma el usuario solo tiene que ingresar `1` si quiere estar en la primera fila y no `0` (que seria la primera fila en programación)

Pero aquí hay 2 cosas interesantes, solo estamos haciendo esto para una fila y que hay de la otra?, pues según tus preguntas anteriores, lo que quieres hacer es un sistema para tomar un asiento de un avión, por esta razón no veo tan necesario separar las filas, pero no importa.

Para hacer la estructura de este avión, podemos combinar ambas filas (`fila1`,`fila2`)

```py
import math #nos servira para luego

#agrupamos las filas en una lista
asientos = [fila1,fila2]
```

Luego podemos hacer una búsqueda para obtener la fila o podemos hacer algo mas *simple*, podemos hacer un `if` (operador ternario) para que nos de la fila donde se ubique el asiento

```py
asiento = 23
#la variable fila tendra el numpy array dependiendo del asiento
fila = asientos[0] if asiento in asientos[0] else asientos[1]

#obtenemos la fila exacta en que se encuentra
num_fila = math.ceil(asiento/6)-1
#obtenemos el asiento
asiento = fila[num_fila][(num_fila+1)*6-asiento]
```

Luego solo nos falta reemplazarlo como lo hicimos en el ejemplo anterior

Comment: esque mi profesor literal nos pidió esto                                                                                   1. Ver asientos disponibles
2. Comprar asiento
3. Anular vuelo
4. Modificar datos de pasajero
5. Salir
un menu tal que asi y que en mostrar asientos mostrará por pantalla todos los asientos disponibles con su número de asiento y los no disponibles los con una “X” y nos pide un arreglo multidimensional

Comment: Pues... y te pidió usar numpy?

Comment: sim osea para usar el arreglo multidimensional nos hace ocupar numpy

Comment: Mmm.... pues entonces no se va a poder,  lo puedeshacwr usando listas de listas (matrices)

Comment: y como sería asi :C?

Comment: reemplazas los numpy array por listas, en un momento edito la respuesta